# How can I best position Olaf for Effective Jungling Axe Throws?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've just started learning to jungle, and I've found that there is one key to jungling as Olaf, in my experience: positioning Olaf and effectively striking the maximum number of monsters while throwing the axe the shortest distance, to reduce its cooldown instantly without having to run around to retrieve it.

I'm having issues finding the right spots for all the creep camps.  Blue doesn't make too much difference, because with a leash they're moving anyway so they can be aligned however you like.  Wolves I've been hit or miss on, but they're also not too much of an issue because they're all melee, so after the first axe, they're easy to hit.

It is the wraiths and red buff camp that I am in the dark on.  I find myself running around a lot to hit the wraiths with my axes, and the red camp, since 2 of them don't move, I wind up only hitting 2/3 at a time, and that's causing my jungle time to be significantly slowed.

I've watched TheOddOne's videos on YouTube, but I can't seem to get the same position that he has in the video where he hits all 3 of the red buff camp, nor at the wraith camp.  Are there any good quality images of where I should be standing, and where my cursor should be, to utilize my axe throw to the greatest potential in the jungle as Olaf, specifically on red buff and wraith camps?  I'm also concerned with the top/bottom mirroring--I seem to be better at certain camps on top vs bottom, and the reverse for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many more attempts, I have come up with the placement (at the Red buff), but I do not yet have a screenshot to back it up.  I will attempt to explain it as best I can, and will try to get a screenshot at some point, to update the answer.

The biggest issue I was having was that I would throw the axe, hit all 3, but not be able to pick it up to lower the cooldown, without moving.  What I've found however, is if you stand behind Red, between Red and the smaller vertically aligned creep, as close to red as possible without attacking, you can throw the axe to the other side of Red (so that your cursor is the red attack sword, but it is on the opposite side of Red.)

It may take a bit of experimentation, but this seems to hit all 3, and causes a reduced cooldown.  The axe has a larger radius of effect than I expected, so you do not need to place the cursor all the way on the far creep.

Hopefully this helps someone.  If no one else, it helped me.